# How to access svn repo via subclipse?

Tags: svn, opensuse

I want to use svn on my root server so I performed following steps:

1. install subversion using yast
2. add group svn
3. add a user with group svn
4. create svn repo using svnadmin create
5. chgrp on repo folder
6. Checkout with subclipse

My repo is now located in `/root/opt/svn/myproject`

I want to access via http. So this is my `subversion.conf`

```
<Location /opt/svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /opt/svn

   SVNListParentPath On
    # Limit write permission to list of valid users.

    # Require SSL connection for password protection.
    # SSLRequireSSL
    AuthType Basic
    # Message to give to the committer
    AuthName "Write access requires a password"
    # File listing users with write (commit) access
    AuthUserFile /srv/svn/user_access/svn_passwdfile
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I followed this tutorial: http://www.korecky.org/?p=168&langswitch_lang=en

How can I access my repo? What is the correct url?

Comment: What has PuTTY to do with that? I thought you wanted to check it out via subclipse?

Comment: @mailq, many Windows SVN clients use putty(plink) for to build the SSH conection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the docs about the [repository URLs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch02s03.html#svn-ch-2-table-1)?

If you are expecting to connect via putty, then you probably want to use a url like.

```
svn+ssh://full.domain.name/full/path/to/repository
```

Unless your repository actually is `/my.Project`, then I suspect your path is wrong.

Comment: My repo is on root/opt/svn/myProject